# Control a Winforms tooltip's location

Tags: winforms, tooltip

Is there any way to control a tooltip's location on a Winform? I can handle the Popup event, but in the event handler I can only change the size, not the location. I could use the OnMouseEnter/Leave events of the control to manually show a tooltip, but then I lose the benefits of the AutomaticDelay property of a normal tooltip.

Comment: I am very much interested in showing and hiding a tooltip manually inside `OnMouseEnter/Leave` events because I want to do so conditionally. Can you think of an example on a web where such thing is being done?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [ToolTip.Show](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.tooltip.show.aspx) method has some overloads that allow this.  Check it out.